# Find missing references in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-macros

I have a huge solution file with lots of projects in it. I suspect that some of the projects that are referenced to by other projects are missing from solution. Is there an easy way to detect missing references in Visual Studio? (I am using 2008)

Answer (score 0):

If you try and compile and references are missing Visual Studio will give you compile errors for the missing references.

Comment: It seems that Visual Studio only detect direct missing references. But if a dll references another dll, it won't detect it and crash when running.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 refuses to compile the SLN: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573411/visual-studio-2012-the-project-file-has-been-renamed-or-is-no-longer-in-the-s

Comment: But if you compile with msbuild, you'll get linker errors for missing references.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google based on your subject turned up [Reference Assistant](http://concurrentaccess.com/referenceassistant/).  Which has a 30 day free trial.

Disclaimer:  I haven't used the product or any of the companies products.

Answer (score 0):

I use the macro *FindMissingFiles* from [here](http://www.8bit.rs/blog/2009/08/a-macro-to-find-missing-files-in-visual-studio-solutions/) which is a modification of [HOWTO: Navigate the files of a solution from a Visual Studio .NET macro or add-in](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2006/MZ2006004.aspx).  It's pretty raw but does the job.

Comment: But it only finds missing files, not referenced projects.