# Solution won't allow debug/build/clean after merge visual studio 2012

Tags: c, git, visual-studio-2012, projects-and-solutions

When merging two branches, the Visual Studio solution and project files did not match, so they had to be merged manually.Now when i try to build or clean the solution I get the following message:
"The debugger cannot continue running the process. The project file '' has been renamed or no longer is in the solution."
Is there a(not brute force) way to understand what is wrong with the files and fix it.
What does this error message actually mean?

The solution is made of 10 projects, 2 of which can be used as startup-one for unit tests and one for functional testing. 
When I tried taking these file from one of the branches there were many files missing on either side.
Setting the correct startup project does not help.

Comment: Did you try to set "MSBuild project build output verbosity" VS option to "Diagnostic" and examine the output window after (re)build?

Comment: I cannot run a (re)build, I get that error message when i try

Comment: I got it. I had a similar problem with property sheets in C++ native solution. I couldn't fix it. I had to remove all property sheets from solution and add them all again.

Comment: Apparently project dependencies' Id's did not change correctly for one of the startup projects. I cannot upvote your comments for some reason :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17600282/3779620) 
Long story short, one of the projects did not update the Id's of its dependencies correctly, resulting in it being unable to use them. 
Also, one moral of the story is don't let your branches diverge for over a year children.